# Is there any way to apply the concept of a partial to my application controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, applicationcontroller

I put all methods that I use more than once into my application controller. This helps keep my controllers lean, except for my application controller. After years of doing this, my application controller is huge.

I enjoy having the ability to break down complex views into partials. And I also put elements that can be accessed in more than one view into partials.

I would love to have the same principle applied to my application controller... e.g. 'partials' that could be accessed in my application controller that would be the equivalent of a view's use of `<%= render 'whatchamacallit' %>`.

I've read documentation on the application controller and haven't found this ability. Is there a way of doing this now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered using modules?

Comment: thanks @Bohdan. I'll look into that.

Comment: good luck! you may also consider using concerns http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: Promising @Bohdan. Researching. Created 1 module so far and it seems that this is going to work for me. Thanks.